# STL lower_bound not spec compliant

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-c++-2005

The following code doesn't compile in C++Builder 2009 or in Visual C++ 2005 when the macro `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` equals `1` but if commented out it will. It appears the `lower_bound` function isn't spec compliant. The library is swapping the arguments. Here's an excerpt form the spec. `value` should always be the second argument.  Am I wrong?

NOTE: The test code wasn't designed to run.  It was designed to illustrate the library bug.

#### C++ Spec excerpt

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
ForwardIterator
lower_bound(ForwardIterator first, 
            ForwardIterator last, 
            const T& value, 
            Compare comp);
```

> 25.3.3.1.3
>
> Returns: The furthermost iterator i in the range [first, last] such that for any iterator j in the range [first, i) the following corresponding conditions hold: *j < value or comp(*j, value) != false

#### Visual Studio error message

> Msg: error C2664: 'double mike::operator ()(const double,const char *) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'const double'
>
> File: c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility
>
> Line No: 314

#### Test Code

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 1  // needs to be in the stdafx.h file for Visual Studio
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct mike : public std::binary_function<double, char*, double> {
   double operator() (const double i, const char*) const {
      return i;
   }
};

int main()
{
   double r[] = {0};
   std::lower_bound(r, r, "", mike());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: error C2664: 'double mike::operator ()(const double,const char *) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'const double' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility 314

Comment: Unless you _really_ need to use an older version of Visual C++, you should be using Visual C++ 2010.  There are many, many bugs that have been fixed since Visual C++ 2005 was released.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Visual C++ 2005 C++ Standard Library implementation (see ["Binary predicate paramter to `lower_bound` assumes that both parameters are the same type when compiling in debug mode" on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/100097/binary-predicate-paramter-to-lower-bound-assumes-that-both-parameres-are-the-same-type-when-compiling-in-debug-mode)).

The bug was fixed in Visual C++ 2008.